# How to delete an element of cartesian product of a two lists in Terraform?

Tags: azure, terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-nsg

I would like to create a set of network security (nsg) rules in Azure between different subnets by using Terraform. For that purpose, i have written the below code:

```
#here, a set of subnets are created according to the value of count. 
resource "azurerm_subnet" "mysubnets" {
    count = var.subnet_number
    name = join("-", ["subnet", count.index])
    resource_group_name = var.rgname
    virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.Global_VNet.name
    address_prefix = join(".", ["10.0", "${count.index}", "0/24"])
}
```

`product` variable below is created in order to create nsg rule with subnet pairs. It  enables to iterate over the subnets pair. I retrieve address_prefixes inside the  declaration of resource azurerm_network_security_rule

```
locals {
  product = "${setproduct(azurerm_subnet.mysubnets, azurerm_subnet.mysubnets)}"
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "myNSGrule" {
      count                       = var.subnet_number * var.subnet_number
      source_address_prefix       = lookup(element(local.product, count.index)[0],"address_prefix")
      destination_address_prefix  = lookup(element(local.product, count.index)[1],"address_prefix")
      name                        = join("-", ["nsg","${count.index}"])
      priority                    = 100 + count.index
      direction                   = "Outbound"
      access                      = "Allow"
      protocol                    = "*"
      source_port_range           = "*"
      destination_port_range      = "*"
      resource_group_name         = var.rgname
      network_security_group_name = azurerm_network_security_group.myNSG.name

}


resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "Global_VNet" {
  name                = var.vnetname
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
  address_space       = var.VNetAddressSpace
  location            = var.location
}

resource "azurerm_network_security_group" "myNSG" {
  name                = join("-", ["${var.rgname}", "nsg"])
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.rgname
}


#NSG subnet association
 resource "azurerm_subnet_network_security_group_association" "LabNSGAssoc" {
  count                     = var.subnet_number
  subnet_id                 = azurerm_subnet.mysubnets[count.index].id
  network_security_group_id = azurerm_network_security_group.myNSG.id
}
```

I want to avoid nsg rules where destination and source prefix are identical as below:
[image]

I have tried several different Terraform function but couldn't find a solution. Do you have any ideas?

Comment: Is it unclear how the config relates to the question, but it sounds like you are asking how to create a Map from a List, where every element is a key, and an array of every element that is not identical to the key is the value. Is that accurate?

Comment: i guess in a set variable, all the elements are different. But you got the idea. I have tried distinct() function with distinct(setproduct(azurerm_subnet.mysubnets, azurerm_subnet.mysubnets)). But it doesn't eliminate. I will add some more comments to clarify it.

Comment: Without specific information about your config, you should be able to do something with a lambda like: `[for i, j in zipmap(<subnet_list>, <subnet_list>): {i: j} if i != j]`. Although that would probably work, it does also feel kind of suboptimal as I am speculating on your config and just kind of spitballing here.

Comment: i am trying to realize that algorytm within Terraform

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can filter a collection using the optional `if` clause of a [`for` expression](https://www.terraform.io/docs/configuration/expressions.html#for-expressions):

```
locals {
  product = [
    for pair in setproduct(azurerm_subnet.mysubnets, azurerm_subnet.mysubnets) : pair
    if pair[0] != pair[1]
  ]
}
```

The `if` clause filters out any elements where the given condition doesn't hold, so with the above condition the result will include only the items where the first and second element of `pair` are different.

Comment: With this loop, i got two entry of the same firewall rule with different priorities although i avoid nsg rules where destination and source prefix are identical.

Comment: It strangely creates same amount of nsg rules although it should be less as it should be eliminating nsg rules where destination and source prefix are identical

Comment: If you changed nothing except the `local.product` expression then the `count` expression in your security rule would be incorrect. You could try using `length(local.product)` instead of `var.subnet_number * var.subnet_number` to get the number _after_ filtering, although that will not work if the subnets are not known at planning time. If you need more help with `count` here then I'd suggest asking a new question, because that's different than what you originally asked here.

Comment: that's right. I got 
Error: Invalid count argument

  on network.tf line 37, in resource "azurerm_network_security_rule" "myNSGrule":
  37:       count                       = length(local.product)

The "count" value depends on resource attributes that cannot be determined
until apply, so Terraform cannot predict how many instances will be created.
To work around this, use the -target argument to first apply only the
resources that the count depends on.

Comment: it is working with the correct number of count. "var.subnet_number * var.subnet_number - var.subnet_number" is working as count number.